# Linq sum under certain conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, group-by

I am currently working on a mvc project and trying to make some linq statements in order to calculate some costs for a logistic enterprise.

```
           IEnumerable<Tagestourauswertung> query =
           from ls in db.Lieferscheine join l in db.Lieferadressen on ls.Lieferadresse.LieferadresseID
           equals l.LieferadresseID join tb in db.TagestourBestehtAusLieferadresse on l.LieferadresseID equals tb.LieferadresseID
           join t in db.Tagestouren on tb.TagestourID equals t.TagestourID
           join f in db.Fahrer on t.Fahrer.FahrerID equals f.FahrerID
           where ls.Lieferdatum.Year == tb.Uhrzeit.Year && ls.Lieferdatum.Month == tb.Uhrzeit.Month && ls.Lieferdatum.Day == tb.Uhrzeit.Day

           group new { ls, l, tb, t, f } by new { t.TagestourID, t.Name, t.VorlageStandardtour.StandardtourID } into deb

               select new Tagestourauswertung()
           {
               TagestourID = deb.Key.TagestourID,
               Tagestourname = deb.Key.Name,
               StandardtourID = deb.Key.StandardtourID,
               Deckungsbeitrag = deb.Sum(x => x.ls.Deckungsbeitrag) - deb.Sum(y => y.t.Kosten) - deb.Sum(z => z.t.Zeit * z.f.KostenProStunde),
               Rentabilität = deb.Sum(x => x.ls.Deckungsbeitrag) / (deb.Sum(y => y.t.Kosten) + deb.Sum(z => z.t.Zeit * z.f.KostenProStunde))
           };
        List<Tagestourauswertung> TagesAuswertung = new List<Tagestourauswertung>();
        TagesAuswertung.AddRange(query);
        return View(TagesAuswertung);
```

This is my code, I know its German and some of you might have difficulties but let me explain you very shortly, what I want to reach:
We have in db.Lieferscheine some adresses saved, where we deliver. These adresses have an ID and also have the yield saved.
In the table Tagestour, we have our daily tours saved with an ID and also the costs.

The adresses from the table Lieferscheine can belong to the daily tours.
So one daily tour can contain many adresses.

My problem is, If I want to calculate my win, so when I want to use the formula:

```
 sum(yield) - costs of the tour
```

I have the problem, that for example in the case that 3 adresses from the table Lieferscheine belong to one tour, the system also multiplies the costs of a tour by 3, even though the complete cost of a tour is for example 200$ it will make 600 of it.

How can I manage to solve it?
I only want the costs of a tour to be summed when there are two or more adresses saved in the table Lieferscheine, which belong to different daily tours.
In the case that they all or some of them belong to one daily tour, it should only be reduced by the costs of this tour and not multiplied by the amound of adresses, which belong to the tour...

My calculation is under select

{ Deckungsbeitrag= deb.Sum(x=>x.ls.Deckungsbeitrag(this is the yield from the table Lieferscheine)) - deb.Sum(y=>y.t.Kosten(this is the cost of a certain tour)

This part is where I have the biggest problem.
I hope some of you can give me some advice

Comment: It's really hard to follow in a foreign language, you'd get more answers if you converted the code snippet to English

Comment: Indeed, try to make an abstract of your problem, making an easy to understand query that contains only the important elements. While doing so you may even find the solution by yourself.

Comment: First thing to do: rewrite it using navigation properties (like `Tagestour.TagestourBestehtAusLieferadressen`). Many of these problems melt away if you remove these verbose and obfuscating joins.